# Dynamically add text to PNG in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I have floor plans for apartments and information in excel sheets and from the internet, and I'm analyzing them in R.

I would like to dynamically add text to each room, say the square feet of the room compared to average etc. To do this, I figured I have to read the text of the png (e.g. bedroom), and merge with my information in R, then somehow add the text to the png.

Has anyone done something similar, and is it even possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the `magick` package in `R`. Here is a [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) . You can add text to png files by using `image_annotate()` function.

Comment: You will probably need to OCR the png to get the text.  The `tesseract` package can help with that.